# Linux awk command for isolation

Tags: linux, awk

If I had a file with hundreds of records, how do I isolate let's say the first 5 lines and display them using "awk"? I am trying to display a few lines from a file with several records of names, date etc.

Comment: See http://awk.info/?awk1line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works:

```
awk 'FNR<=5' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you like, since you have none input data or output example
If you like to print the 5 first line of a file using `awk`, you can do:

```
awk 'n {print;n--}' n=5 file
```

or just

```
awk 'NR<6' file
```

Answer (score 2):

> let's say the first 5 lines and display

Question is tagged for `awk` but `head` is what you need. Use the right tool for the job. Although you can reinvent the wheel with `awk`

```
head -5 <file_name>
```